# cherry-pick changes of multiple non sequential commits from remote branches to "master" branch in single commit

Tags: git

[image]

I have created a master remote branch(A), then I did a branching of master as branch(B). I did three commits on branch(B). But I want to cherry-pick changes only from commit1 & commit3 and push them as a single commit in my master branch. Can anyone suggest me a way to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the `-n` option of `git cherry-pick`, which prevents creating a commit.

```
git cherry-pick -n commit1
git cherry-pick -n commit3
git commit
```

Also you can cherry-pick multiple commits at once:

```
git cherry-pick -n commit1 commit3
git commit
```

Comment: I think the `-n` option can be problematic if you have to resolve merge conflicts in any of the cherry-picks.

Answer (score 2):

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick commit1
git cherry-pick commit3
git reset HEAD~2 --soft
git commit
git push origin master
```

Update: change HEAD^2 to HEAD~2

Comment: "HEAD^2" <-- you mean HEAD~2?

Comment: @jbu yes. Thank you. I made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Do two cherry-picks, then squash the two new commits:

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick commit1
git cherry-pick commit3
git rebase -i @~2
```

In your editor, select "squash" for the second commit. Edit the commit message to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do

```
git checkout -b joined
git cherry-pick commit1 commit3
# fix potential merge conflicts
git checkout master
git merge --squash joined
```